# Next refresh time visual in PBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to Display the next refresh date and time visual in PBI on basis of daily refresh from 9 am to 5 pm?

I have tried some methods which are not giving me any results. Please suggest me some ideas, Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you the date/time of the last refresh?